# increasing performance of listbox in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone app where I am using a listbox.I am binding some images from media library.But it is taking so much time to load .So if there are lot of images in media library it will take so much time.

```
private List<img> _galleryImages = new List<img>(); 

public void getImages()
{
    try
    {
        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        var pictures = mediaLibrary.Pictures;
        foreach (var picture in pictures)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(picture.GetImage());
            img mediaImage = new img();
            mediaImage.Imgs = image;
            _galleryImages.Add(mediaImage);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}

   public class img
{
    public BitmapImage Imgs { get; set; }
}
```

in xaml....

```
            <toolkit:LongListSelector  x:Name="imageList" IsFlatList="True" >
            <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Image Name="im" Source="{Binding img}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector>

 private void imageList_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary();
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(mediaLibrary.Pictures[imageList.SelectedIndex].GetImage());
        image1.Source = image;
    }
```

So please give me some tips to load images from media library to listbox so fastly....

Comment: Use a ListBox that implements virtualization. Like the `LongListSelector` or Telerik's `RadDataBoundListBox`

Comment: You also should use Thumbnails instead of full size images.

Comment: @Anton-Thanks for replying,But I am using a listbox with images as I have said.So after selecting listbox image ,the selected item is bound to a big image source,I just want to know how to convert this thumbnail to high resolution image.

Comment: Probably by using some kind of ID? It's hard to guess and you didn't show any code.

Comment: Hi Igrali,I have updated my question and added codes .Actually I am taking thumbnails,So how to convert these thumbnails to high resolution image in my image.source

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [LongListSelector](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector.aspx) to load more images while the user scrolls the list:

> Windows Phone users love to swipe their phones smoothly to get to the information they want. Whether it’s swiping horizontally via panorama and pivot controls, or swiping vertical lists in areas such as the People Hub, users view the phone as a small window into an infinite amount of useful information.
>
> We as developers have a responsibility to make it look and feel like the information is always available in the viewport while users are swiping around. To maintain this perception of infinite scrolling, we would like to have all the data loaded in memory. However, for most practical scenarios, we cannot possibly have all the data pre-loaded. The News feed in the People Hub is a classic example of fetching fresh data from a web service.
>
> In this post, I describe how to pre-fetch information to create an infinite scrollable list for Windows Phone 7.5 using the LongListSelector control. This approach is sometimes called the "Loading...pattern.”

Answer (score 0):

- It's important to use virtualizing lists (e.g. use ListBox [with `VirtualizedStackPanel`, default] not a `ScrollViewer` with an `ItemsControl`).
- Maybe you can use the [LowProfileImageLoader](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx) to fasten image loading (i'm not sure if it really is needed in WP8)
- Try to improve the loading of the images (e.g. faster server, avoid proxies, etc.). Where is your bottleneck?
- I developed the `LowProfileImageLoader` further to my [ImageHelper](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ImageHelper) class and also developed a [ExtendedListBox](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ExtendedListBox). With these two components you can avoid loading images while scrolling which improves scrolling performance.
- The `ExtendedListBox` even has a scrolled to end event to load more elements (don't load all elements at once). I think this is also possible with the `LongListSelector` control, see @BartW's answer.

Show us some more code so that we can help you better...

Comment: Thanks for replying Rico,I have seen your lowProfileImageLoader but the problem is,as I have said above I am binding listbox selecteditem to a big image source,I found that if i am loading thumbnails it is loading so fastly,So I want to know after selecting listbox selected item ,how to convert thumbanails to high resolution image.

Comment: Are the images itself big or are there a big number of images? How do u access the images? On an own server?

Comment: Hi Rico,I have updated my question and added codes .Actually I am taking thumbnails,So how to convert these thumbnails to high resolution image in my image.source